# Single index or multiple index

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, logstash, elastic-stack

My environment architecture is I have 15 server. The details as below

Group 1 (Standalone)

- server 1 (2 app)
- server 2 3 app)
- server 3 (2 app)
- server 4 (3 app)

Group 2 (master and slave)

- server 5 master (2 app)
- server 6 slave (2 app)

Group 3 (master and 2 slave)

- server 7 master (3 app)
- server 8 slave (3 app)
- server 9 slave (3 app)

Group 4 (1 master 5 slave)

- server 10 master (1 app)
- server 11 slave (1 app)
- server 12 slave (1 app)
- server 13 slave (1 app)
- server 14 slave (1 app)
- server 15 slave (1 app)

Each application have 15 -20 logs

What is the best way in creating the index in logstash?

Is below better  for index pattern
app_name-log_name-YYMMDD

Later i want to visual in Kibana in below form table panel form consist of time, message based on respective log name

The below is data for a sinngle log. other log have simillar pattern but different data. i want to dispaly only for single log show single table

[image: ![image|690x236](upload://12Xidsw81u6s4loDp5KDArIW7vl.jpeg)]

Answer (score 0):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#_writing_to_different_indices_best_practices has a good starting point about creating custom index names. In general, I would think about combining into a single index what has both similar lifecycle (keep the data for 30 days for example) and similar structure (most of the same fields). As long as you have a field for the app, you can filter on that and it will work just as well.

Also, I'd strongly recommend to [use ILM](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-ilm) to get evenly sized indices rather than what happens with a daily index pattern.